# ImportError - Name conflict, parent folder has the same name as another filename

Tags: python, python-import

I have the following folder structure in python:

```
houses/
   models.py
   __init__.py
   view/
      houses.py
      events.py
      __init__.py
```

At the file events.py I have the following line:

```
from houses.models import House
```

Which results me in the following error

> No module named models

I'm pretty much sure it's searching at houses.py file, while what I want is that he searches on the folder houses for the file models.py. How can I tell python to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the python [documentation about intra-package references](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references), you can use a relative import

```
from ..models import House
```

Comment: but i m getting following error ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation on [the module search path](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#tut-searchpath). You can add:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../..")
```

to the beginning of events.py, or modify the environmental variable `PYTHONPATH`.